# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know why I am getting this message as the AJAX is completing and expects JSON coming back.

However, I coded the controller action method such that if all is good, redirects to another view. If there is an error is found, return JSON - an error message.

From the AJAX perspective as I am learning, it will expect JSON back regardless of a good (the redirect) or error situation (I return JSON).

So how do I code that up in the AJAX to recognize that no JSON was returned when it is a good situation as I do the redirect and do not programmatically return anything?

---

The action method executes successfully in the sense that it does the delete, executes the redirect but gets caught on the return and I get the message:

[image]

---

My actions method is:

I have

```
 Task<ActionResult>
```

If I try

```
 Task<JsonResult>
```

I get an error on the redirect statement.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteUserProfile()
    {
        string errorMessage = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            Some code to call the web api...

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Some code...

                // Call the web api - HTTP POST.
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(restOfUrl, argsData);

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
                else
                {
                    // The web api sent an error response.
                    errorMessage = "Server error on deleting the user profile. Reason: " + result.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
           Some code...
        }

        // Return a JSON object to show the error message.
        return Json(errorMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view that has the AJAX that calls the method:

```
    <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="Delete Your Profile">
```

There is a Modal window and on a Yes, executes the AJAX. And I was thinking it would only come back if I pushed the JSON with the error message.

```
        $('.btn-yes11').click(function() {
            $('#myModal11').modal('hide');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUserProfile", "UserProfile")',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(jsondata) {
                    if (jsondata.length > 0)
                    {
                        // Set the error message.
                        $("#jsonErrorMessage").text(jsondata);
                        // Show.
                        $("#jsonErrorMessage").css("display", "block");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Hide.
                        $("#jsonErrorMessage").css("display", "none");
                    }
                 },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to DeleteUserProfile for delete! Status: ' + xhr.status + '. Error: ' + thrownError.toString() + '. Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Hi, you have `errorMessage = "Server error on deleting the user profile. Reason:...` this is not json .

Comment: That message gets sent back, and the AJAX processes it just fine. I display it in the view OK. The problem is when I have a good situation and do the redirect and it comes back with no JSON. Also, how would I pass that back to be JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code for resolving my issue (it no longer does a redirect and always sends back a JSON object):

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteUserProfile()
 {
    string errorMessage = String.Empty;
    bool RedirectSwitch = false;

    try
    {
        Some code to call the web api...

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Some code...

            // Call the web api - HTTP POST.
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(restOfUrl, argsData);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               // Set the switch so that the AJAX call will go to the User controller.
               RedirectSwitch = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // The web api sent an error response.
                errorMessage = "Server error on deleting the user profile. Reason: " + result.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
       Some code...
    }

    if (errorMessage != "")
    {
      // Set an error code which will initiate the AJAX function: 'error: function (error) {}'.
      Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    // Creates JSON representation of anonymous data.
    // Return a JSON object.
    return Json(new { Redirect = RedirectSwitch, ErrorMessage = errorMessage });
}
```

The Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUserProfile", "UserProfile")',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Redirect)
                {
                    // A successful delete - so go to the User controller. To the index action which returns the Views\User\User.cshtml.
                    window.location.href = "/User/Index/";
                }
             },
            error: function (error) {
               // Set the error message from the key/value pair set in the controller: ErrorMessage = errorMessage.
                $("#jsonErrorMessage").text(error.responseJSON.ErrorMessage);
                // Show it.
                $("#jsonErrorMessage").css("display", "block");
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this way may be useful.

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Create(MyObject myObject) 
{
  //AllFine
  return Json(new { IsCreated = True, Content = ViewGenerator(myObject));

  //Use input may be wrong but nothing crashed
  return Json(new { IsCreated = False, Content = ViewGenerator(myObject));  

  //Error
  Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
  return Json(new { IsCreated = false, ErrorMessage = 'My error message');
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "MyController/Create",
     data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
     success: function (result) {
       if(result.IsCreated)
     {
    //... ALL FINE
     }
     else
     {
    //... Use input may be wrong but nothing crashed
     }
   },
    error: function (error) {
            alert("Error:" + erro.responseJSON.ErrorMessage ); //Error
        }
  });
```

Comment: Hardik...that helped me in resolving my issue. I posted the resolution above.